# Google App maker not available to Education customers?

Tags: google-app-maker

Our school Google App Maker application was declined "because your domain was not listed as having G Suite Business seats". We have 1,000+ EDU seats and the App Maker page says that GSFE customers can sign up --  *App Maker is included with G Suite Business and Enterprise editions, as well as, with G Suite for Education.* https://developers.google.com/appmaker/

How can Google Suite for Education customers sign up? I would love to use it for one of my MS classes, I think Google App Maker would be perfect use case for EDU.

Comment: This is not a question that relates to app maker coding or anything relevant. Please get in contact with G Suite Support and ask them https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

From this [page.](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/overview)

I see that it says:

> App Maker is available with G Suite Business, Education, and Enterprise editions. **Sign in to an account provided by your school or employer and start building apps now.**

So I would assume you need to talk to your school's IT department or whomever is in charge and see if they set up accounts, and if so what the credentials are.

Comment: That would be me. Just to clarify that I'm the admin for our school domain who has applied for Google App Maker. Our application was denied "because your domain was not listed as having G Suite Business seats".

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. Have you tried contacting them here: https://gsuite.google.com/support/ ?

Comment: Yes. They can't help. If any other admins are reading that is not support for Google App Maker.

Answer (score 0):

App Maker is not currently available for Education, it is in Early Access for Business and Enterprise customers only, as noted on [the site](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google has conflicting info on various pages. I have seen they are saying AppMaker is available for Business and Enterprise. But I have seen recent pages clearly state that it is available for Education.  They tell you to contact the school admin for access to build an AppMaker app.

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/overview

**App Maker is available with G Suite Business, Education, and Enterprise editions. Sign in to an account provided by your school or employer and start building apps now.**

Google what is the deal?  Why not allow Education to use AppMaker?  At least have clear messages on your developer site.